# Django createView passing current user_id to Modelform

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a calendar app and currently trying to stop people from being about to save an event when they are already busy during that time period. I believe my issue is that the modelForm doesn't have the user_id as part of the form object. how can I pass the user_id so I can use it to filter with the clean().

I tried using get_form_kwargs() but this doesn't seem to be the correct route to take.

Please can you point me in the right direction of how to do this.

view.py

```
class CalendarEventAdd(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = 'calendar_create_event_form.html' 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('calendar_list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.manage = self.request.user
    return super(CalendarEventAdd, self).form_valid(form)

def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(CalendarEventAdd, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user_id'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```

form.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Event
    widgets = {
        'start_time': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
        'end_time': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
        }
    fields = ['avilibility','start_time','end_time']


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # input_formats parses HTML5 datetime-local input to datetime field
    self.fields['start_time'].input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',)
    self.fields['end_time'].input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',)
    
    
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form_start_time = self.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
    form_end_time = self.cleaned_data.get('end_time')
    form_manage_id = self.cleaned_data.get('manage_id')
    between = Event.objects.filter(manage_id=1, end_time__gte=form_start_time, start_time__lte=form_end_time)
    if between:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Already Calendar entry for this time')
    super().clean()
```

model.py

```
class Event(models.Model):

    avilibility_choices = [
    ('Avilible', 'Avilible'),
    ('Busy', 'Busy'),
]
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    manage = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avilibility = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=avilibility_choices, editable=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.avilibility + " - " + str(self.start_time) + " - " + str(self.end_time) + " - " +str(self.id)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('calendar_event_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def get_absolute_url_edit(self):
        return reverse('calendar_event_detail_update', args=[str(self.id)])

    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('event_edit', args=(self.id,))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.avilibility} </a>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you should pass the *primary key* of the user, so:

```
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(CalendarEventAdd, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user_id'] = self.request.user.pk
        return kwargs
```

You can save it in the `EventForm` object:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, user_id=None, **kwargs):   
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_id = user_id
        # input_formats parses HTML5 datetime-local input to datetime field
        self.fields['start_time'].input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',)
        self.fields['end_time'].input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',)
    
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_start_time = self.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
        form_end_time = self.cleaned_data.get('end_time')
        form_manage_id = self.cleaned_data.get('manage_id')
        between = Event.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(
            manage_id=self.user_id,
            end_time__gte=form_start_time,
            start_time__lte=form_end_time
        )
        if between.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Already Calendar entry for this time')
        return super().clean()
```

The `.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)` will exclude the object you are editing, if you later decide to use the `EventForm` not only to *create* but also *update* an `Event` object.

---

> **Note**: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) advises to
> use the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) over
> [**`get_user_model()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model).
> This is safer, since if the authentication app is not yet loaded, the settings
> can still specify the name of the model. Therefore it is better to write:
>
> ```
> from django.conf import settings
>
> class Event(models.Model):
>     # …
>     manage = models.ForeignKey(
>         settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
>         on_delete=models.CASCADE
>     )
> ```